# asp.net mvc - add to cart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Let's say that I have this model

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone explain me, what is the easiest method to put these objects into a cart and make an order?

Comment: How about creating a Cart and Order class ?  Or an Order class that contains a "cart" collection ?

Comment: Can you explain this in more details? I've seen all of the tutorials and still cant get it. I'm looking for the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can achieve your goal.  Here's one approach:

```
public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class CartItem
    {
        public Book Book { get; set;}
        public int Quantity { get; set;}
    }

    public class Order 
    {
        public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set;}
        public int OrderNumber { get; set;}
        public decimal OrderTotal { get; set;}
    }
```

You can then add books to a cart (the cart being `List<CartItems>`) that's contained in an order.

To demonstrate, consider:

```
var book = new Book{ Id = 123, Title = "Hello World", Price = 42.42M };
var cartItem = new CartItem{ Book = book, Quantity = 2 };
var order = new Order{OrderNumber = 66};
order.CartItems = new List<CartItem>(); 
order.CartItems.Add(cartItem);

Console.WriteLine();

foreach(var item in order.CartItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Book ID: " + item.Book.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Book Title: " + item.Book.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("Book Price: " + item.Book.Price);
    Console.WriteLine("Quantity: " + item.Quantity);
    Console.WriteLine("SubTotal: " + item.Quantity * item.Book.Price);
    order.OrderTotal += item.Quantity * item.Book.Price;
}   

Console.WriteLine("Order Total: " + order.OrderTotal);
```

Demo here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/qpi1ku